# Animate (Oscillation) custom drawn shape on Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

Good day.
I am looking for abit of advice.  Before judging, please take note I am new to coding, with only a few weeks of experience.
I am trying to make the cloud shape I have draw onto the canvas, animated, using JavaScript.  (Please see link below to the type of animation I am looking to achieve.)  I have searched everywhere for how to achieve this, but it seems all the links either deal with an actual image, or a rectangle, and not a custom drawn shape.  So my question is this, is it possible to do such an animation on a custom shape, and, if not, what is the best way to go about it to achieve said desired effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 100px;
        padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <canvas id="Canvas" width="700" height="600" style="border:1px solid #005BAB;"></canvas>
    <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // gradients
    var grd = context.createRadialGradient(550, 150, 25, 500, 200, 400);
    grd.addColorStop (0, '#0586f8');
    grd.addColorStop (1, '#015baa');

      // blue block shadow
    context.shadowColor = '#999';
    context.shadowBlur = 35;
    context.shadowOffsetX = 8;
    context.shadowOffsetY = 8;
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    context.beginPath();
    context.fill();

      // blue block
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(50, 35);
    context.lineTo(50, 525);
    context.lineTo(550, 525);
    context.lineTo(550, 35);
    context.closePath();
    context.lineWidth = 0;
    context.strokeStyle = '#999';
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();

        // cloud shadow
      context.shadowColor = '#232323';
      context.shadowBlur = 20;
      context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
      context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
      context.beginPath();
      context.globalAlpha = 0.9;
      context.fill();

        // cloud drawing
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(172, 180);
      context.bezierCurveTo(145, 180, 120, 234, 185, 240);
      context.lineTo(375, 240);
      context.bezierCurveTo(495, 234, 405, 110, 382, 168);
      context.bezierCurveTo(440, 85, 280, 60, 325, 120);
      context.bezierCurveTo(320, 42, 190, 60, 200, 120);
      context.bezierCurveTo(120, 100, 140, 200, 170, 180);
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.fillStyle = 'white';
      context.fill();
      context.strokeStyle();
      context.lineCap = 'round';
      context.lineJoin = 'round';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-oscillation-animation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another canvas with javascript:

```
var cloud = document.createElement('canvas');
cloud.width = <width of the cloud>;
cloud.height = <height of the cloud>;
```

Then draw your cloud onto that canvas. You should adjust your coordinates so that the top left of the cloud's bounding box is at point (0, 0). This way the cloud canvas is only as big as it needs to be.

Then you can treat your cloud just like you would an image.

```
context.drawImage(cloud, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, makes sense now that you say it.  I have been trying to figure this out for the past two weeks, I feel a bit stupid now! haha

Comment: @SydHolmes Glad I could help! If I answered your question, would you mind accepting the answer (clicking the check mark)? :)